# getResourceAsStream works differently on Mac OSX vs. Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, unit-testing, macos, properties

I have a set of unit test cases that depend on a test.properties file.  When I run the tests under Mac OSX or Linux using Maven ('mvn test'), they work fine.  But when running under Windows 7, they can't find the file unless I copy it directly to the class folder.  The code to return the properties is the following two methods:

```
private void loadProperties() {
    try {
         properties.load(HibernateTestCase.class.getResourceAsStream(getPropertiesFilePath()));
    } catch (Exception ioExc) {
        ioExc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getPropertiesFilePath() {
    return File.separator + "test.properties";
}
```

What's the real deal here?  Is it all about the file path being set wrong somewhere?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the file located when it works under Mac and Linux?  What are the classpaths in the different environments.

The assumption from the code would be that the file is in the root of the same jar or dir that HibernateTestCase.class is.

Also, don't bother using File.separator as all Java platforms will accept "/" just fine for resource resolution (and other things).  In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if it caused a problem her, actually though I doubt it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The separator in resource names is always '/'. `File.separator` varies from platform to platform (on UNIX variants it will generally be `/`, on Windows it will not).

Comment: Replacing the last line in my code from File.separator + "test.properties" to just "/test.properties" filled the bill.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either your classpath is different, or you're using a different classloader with different resolution characteristics.